# proof of the derivative of the quotient

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

To prove the derivative of the quotient we do the following

$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)_{+}^{'} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{f(a+h)g(a)-g(a+h)f(a)}{g(a+h)g(a)}}{h} =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)g(a)-f(a)g(a)+f(a)g(a)-f(a)g(a+h)}{g(a+h)g(a)h} =$$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(a)\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}{g(a)g(a+h)} -\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a)\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}}{g(a)g(a+h)} = \left(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{g(a+h)} \right) \left[ \frac{g(a)f'(a)-f(a)g'(a)}{g(a)}\right]  $$

My question would be: why can we assume that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{g(a+h)}= \frac{1}{g(a)}$ ?

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and nonzero at $a$ then the result follows by definition of continuity. These same requirements also allow you to divide by $g(a+h)g(a)$ safely

Comment: $ g $ must be continuous at $ a$, if not, it won"t be differentiable.

Comment: you don't ''assume'' it. It's a condition in order to prove this property. $g$ must be continuous at $a$ and non-zero. The limit is simply a result.